# How to join 3 records as 1 record base on a same date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This are some sample queries I wrote:

```sql
SELECT 
    CAST(datecolumn AS DATE) AS DateColumn, 
    COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM 
    dbo.myTableName 
WHERE 
    status = 'stage1'
GROUP BY CAST(datecolumn AS DATE) ORDER BY DateColumn DESC;


SELECT 
    CAST(datecolumn AS DATE) AS DateColumn, 
    COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM 
    dbo.myTableName 
WHERE 
    status = 'stage2'
GROUP BY CAST(datecolumn AS DATE) ORDER BY DateColumn DESC;
```

This is the output from the 1st query:

```
DateColumn  count
------------------
2022-05-26  23
2022-05-25  51
2022-05-24  39
2022-05-23  55
2022-05-22  27
2022-05-21  90
```

and this is the output from the 2nd query:

```
DateColumn  count
-----------------
2022-05-26  31
2022-05-25  67
2022-05-24  38
2022-05-23  54
2022-05-22  28
```

I want to only have a single query that will output it like this

```
DateColumn  stage1count stage2count
-----------------------------------
2022-05-26  23            31
2022-05-25  51            67
2022-05-24  39            38
2022-05-23  55            54
2022-05-22  27            28
```

Thanks for answer

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
select cast(datecolumn as DATE) as DateColumn,
       sum(case when status = 'stage1' then 1 else 0 end) as stage1count,
       sum(case when status = 'stage2' then 1 else 0 end) as stage2count
from dbo.myTableName
where status in ('stage1', 'stage2')
group by cast(datecolumn as DATE)
order by DateColumn DESC
```

Another note: Most SQL systems treat datecolumn and DateColumn the same, so it is somewhat ambiguous which it is actually using in the group by and order by clauses. I think the order by is using the casted value in the select list, and the groupby might be using the base column (uncasted) but I'm not sure about that. If you want to avoid the ambiguity, you can use a delimited identifier "DateColumn" instead.

@hewszz, you mention that you also need this for the case where you have two tables. This might do the job if you have two tables:

```
select t1.DateColumn, stage1count, stage2count
from (select cast(datecolumn as DATE) as DateColumn,
             count(*) as stage1count
      from dbo.myTableName1
      where status = 'stage1'
      group by cast(datecolumn as DATE)) t1
     full outer join
     (select cast(datecolumn as DATE) as DateColumn,
             count(*) as stage2count
      from dbo.myTableName2
      where status = 'stage2'
      group by cast(datecolumn as DATE)) t2
     on t1.DateColumn = t2.DateColumn
order by t1.DateColumn DESC
```

By grouping each table separately we make sure that DateColumn is unique on each side, so each row will join with at most one row from the other grouped query. By using a full outer join we make sure no rows get lost when we have only a stage1 or a stage2 record for a given day.

Comment: `Most SQL systems treat datecolumn and DateColumn the same` Actually, It depends on the collation used. For case sensitive collation, `datecolumn` <> `DateColumn `

Comment: for `GROUP BY` you must use the column name, not the alias. For `ORDER BY` you may use either the alias or column name

Comment: this worked, thanks. but now i have the similar query(2 columns with date and count) but come from the different table. how do i join it on your query?

Comment: See the edited answer above for a query that uses two separate tables.